# How to categorization course and user by department in open edX

Tags: openedx

I want to categorization course and user by the department.

I have found the option organization in my admin panel  mydomain.com/admin/organizations/ But I can not find any documents.

Can I achieve my target using this option?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome on StackOverflow Rahul,

It would be better if you elaborate more on your requirements although organisation in course of Open edX is for categorisation also and part of course key you can filter courses based on organisation in elastic search, but if you want extra functionality then you have to create a django app in it for categorisation.

Also for User you can add extra fields in UserProfile model for Department.

Comment: Ritesh Thanks for the reply, I just want to add multiple departments, Each department has separate users and courses. Which is the right option for me organization or Microsites https://raccoongang.com/blog/5-benefits-open-edx-microsites/ ?

Comment: In that scenario microsites works for you and in Open edX microsites are based on organisations so you can create number of microsites equal to number of organisations. Where each microsite will be mapped with organisation which you can do at mydomain.com/admin/microsite_configuration/micrositeorganizationmapping/

Comment: Thank you Ritech, I am trying to configure Microsite to following this URL  https://github.com/mirjamsk/edx-microsite-tutorial .  Is it working in native open edX or Follows any other way to configure Microsites?

Comment: The document you are following worked for me as well but it was with ficus, about latter versions I'm not sure will it work with them or not.